# База данных для мобильного приложения(андроид)

Tags: android, сервер, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Я сформировал мобильное приложение, к которому необходимо подключить БД. Естественно, пароли и прочую информацию пользователя на локалке хранить - ад, поэтому на уме было несколько вариантов реализации(условие: данных в БД будет много):

1. Выбор облачной БД. Проблема состоит в том, что сейчас ведущие компании в этой области закрыли доступ к оплате тарифа, а танцы с бубном устраивать не хочется.
2. Использовать БД на удалённом сервере.

Во втором случае есть проблема: понятия не имею где лучше создать удалённый сервер.

Поэтому прошу помощи и советов где это лучше реализовать или, быть может, есть и другие способы реализации подобной задачи?

Comment: selectel норм подходит для этого

Comment: FireBase можно глянуть.

Answer (score -1):

> понятия не имею где лучше создать удалённый сервер.

Любой шаред-хостинг с поддержкой нужной СУБД или ВПС.
Нужные характеристики зависят нагрузок.